# OpenCV for Android - Mat.get(row, col, double[])

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, mat

I want to access some pixels in my Mat. Below is an example.

How do I get similar effects in Java? I can not use function Mat.get(...) because returns double[].
Can anyone help?

In C++

```
Mat saturation;
float sat[256];
for(int i=0; i<256; i++) {
    sat[i]=saturation.at<float>(i,0);
}
```

In Java

```
Mat saturation = new Mat();
float[] sat = new float[256];
for(int i=0; i<256; i++){
    sat[i] = ???
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback :)  -  maybe if you find the time you could write down your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Create a float array of size 1, then call the get method with that array.

i.e.

```
float[] element = new float[1];
mat.get(row, column, element);
```

You can also get the entire row, or partial number of elements, if you create a bigger `float[]` array - as calling `get` will fill up the array.